# how to call methods of a interface implemented in a class?

Tags: c#, interface

And i have one interface

```
 public  interface IMethod
 {
     String Add(string str);
     Boolean Update(string str);
     Boolean Delete(int id);
 }
```

I have declared another Interface Like this 
which has IMethod as property.

```
public interface IFoo
{
     IMethod MethodCaller { get  ; set; }  
}
```

Now I gone implement IFoo interface in my one of class and from which i want to call IMethods method.

Class implementation

```
 public MyClass : IFoo
 { 
     public IMethod MethodCaller{ get  ; set; }  
 }
```

How do i do it ? how do i call Add **Update Delete method** from **MyClass**

**MyClasses that implement IMethod as follows :**

```
public class foo1:IMethod
{

         public String Add(string str){ return string.Empty;}

         Boolean Update(string str){//defination}

         Boolean Delete(int id){ //defination}
}

public class foo2:IMethod
{

         public String Add(string str){ return string.Empty;}

         Boolean Update(string str){//defination}

         Boolean Delete(int id){ //defination}
}
```

Comment: ? what is the class that implements IMethod? your MyClass only implements IFoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside a class:**

```
public MyClass : IFoo   
{
   public void CallAllMethodsOfIIMethodImpl()
   {
       if (this.MethodCaller != null)
       {
          this.MethodCaller.Add( ... );
          this.MethodCaller.Delete( ... );
          this.MethodCaller.Update( ... );
       }
   }
}
```

**Outside:**

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
if (instance.MethodCaller != null)
{
   instance.MethodCaller.Add( ... );
   instance.MethodCaller.Delete( ... );
   instance.MethodCaller.Update( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't defined any concrete class that implements `IMethod` - you only have defined a *property* that is of type `IMethod` - now you need to assign a concrete class to this property so you can call the methods on it. Once you have done that you can simply call methods on your `MethodCaller` property:

```
string result = MethodCaller.Add(someFoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `myClass` is an instance of `MyClass` and the `MethodCaller` has been set to a concrete implementation, you can call the methods like this:

```
myClass.MethodCaller.Add(...);
myClass.MethodCaller.Update(...);
myClass.MethodCaller.Delete(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an inner class which `implements` `IMethod` interface.

```
public MyClass : IFoo
 { 
   private TestClass _inst;
   public IMethod MethodCaller
   { 
     get 
        {
         if(_inst==null)
           _inst=new TestClass();
         return _inst;
        }
      set 
        {
          _inst=value;
         }  
    }
   public class TestClass : IMethod
   {
     public String Add(string str) {}
     public Boolean Update(string str) {}
     public Boolean Delete(int id) {}
   }
 }
```

Invoke methods:

```
MyClass instance=new MyClass();
instance.MethodCaller.Add(..);
```

OR

```
 IMethod call=new MyClass().MethodCaller;
 call.Add(..);
```